# Different Terminal Colors under same user

Tags: gnome-terminal, colors

How would I be able to run multiple terminal instances, each with their own color style or color profile simultaneously, under the same user?

Comment: this is only good till u execute the next command and once you press ctrl +l   its again the same. or open a file its effect wear outs

Comment: You are right! retracted my close-vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gnome-terminal allows you to create multiple profiles. In Edit->Preferences create as many as you wish, possibly each with different color scheme, different font etc. Right clicking allows you to switch profile at any time.